# Multiple interactive graphs in single HTML/page

Tags: python, altair

Is there a function in altair that can integrate multiple graphs in single page/HTML ?

I am generating graphs from multiple .csv files, I am able to save graphs separately but was looking for a way to save in single "html".

I found a similar question here: [altair-viz/altair#1422](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1422), though couldn't find an example on its implementation for reference. Can anyone please share an example on this.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to combine multiple charts into a single chart, you can use concatenation:

```
(chart1 | chart2).save('charts.html')
```

If for some reason you'd like the charts to be rendered separately and the two renderings embedded into a single HTML page, this is possible, but Altair has no built-in functionality for that.

The best approach would be to construct an HTML template using [vega-embed](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed) directly, and insert the output of `chart.to_json()` in the correct place in the template.

Here is a simple example, from which you can use standard HTML/CSS approaches to customize the layout if you wish:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

two_charts_template = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@{vega_version}"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@{vegalite_version}"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@{vegaembed_version}"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="vis1"></div>
<div id="vis2"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  vegaEmbed('#vis1', {spec1}).catch(console.error);
  vegaEmbed('#vis2', {spec2}).catch(console.error);
</script>
</body>
</html>
"""


df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(5), 'y': range(5)})

chart1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(x='x', y='y')
chart2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(x='x', y='y')

with open('two_charts.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(two_charts_template.format(
        vega_version=alt.VEGA_VERSION,
        vegalite_version=alt.VEGALITE_VERSION,
        vegaembed_version=alt.VEGAEMBED_VERSION,
        spec1=chart1.to_json(indent=None),
        spec2=chart2.to_json(indent=None),
    ))
```

Comment: The HTML template creation approach doesnt preserve the selection across plots. Do you have any other solution works with selection across the plots

Comment: If you want selections to be linked across charts, use the first strategy I mentioned above: build a single chart using concatenation.

Comment: Thanks Jake. That worked. But that creates a single chart combining the two. I want to charts to be placed in different positions from each other. Each chart is separated by some HTML contents, but still remain interactive